# 2 Column responsive layout with sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to create a 2 column layout which drops to 1 when it reaches mobile size.

I am using a responsive pattern template, however, when I put it into litmus to test the sidebar just shrinks instead of actually dropping below the main content.

any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```css
/* Column Drop Layout Pattern CSS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  td[class="pattern"] .col {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  td[class="pattern"] .col:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="pattern">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="col" width="400" align="left" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #333; padding-right: 20px;">
                  <h1 style="margin-top: 0;">Main Column</h1>
                  <p style="padding-bottom: 10px; line-height: 20px !important;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh.
                    Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend
                    arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.
                  </p>
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x50/333&text=CTA»" alt="" style="display: block; border: 0;" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td class="col" width="200" align="left" valign="top" style="background: #ebebeb;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 20px;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #666; padding-bottom: 10px;">Sidebar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="14" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #666;">&bull;</td>
                      <td align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">Bullet 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #666;">&bull;</td>
                      <td align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">Bullet 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #666;">&bull;</td>
                      <td align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">Bullet 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #666;">&bull;</td>
                      <td align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">Bullet 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20" align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #666;">&bull;</td>
                      <td align="left" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">Bullet 5</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    td.pattern .col {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    td.pattern .col:first-child { margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```

Should work, also: what client/browser does it crash in litmus?

Comment: Thanks, I tried the media query you suggested but it didn't work. And I was trying to edit it using the litmus email builder in chrome but it just shrinks down instead of dropping

Answer (score 0):

You are using table structure and your left and right blocks are wrapped withing **`td`** element so its not practically possible to show a `td` under another `td` element.

it means you should change you html and write it either with div or another element

Comment: Ok thanks, Ideally I am just trying to get 2 tables side by side and when the screen size gets smaller the 2nd table drops below the first.